# Bootstrap templates auto-generated?

Tags: flask, flask-bootstrap

I'm having trouble setting up Flask-bootstrap. From the [official documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html), it seems like all I have to do is apply the Bootstrap constructor to my `app`, and the templates will be automatically created. So I tried this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Where is Bootstrap?</h1>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run it, no new directories are created and I find no base templates anywhere. Am I missing a critical step? Is there some directory to be created first (I tried creating `templates` and `static` and setting the permissions to 777 but that didn't help)? Or perhaps the base templates are first to be generated from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base templates are part of the Flask-Bootstrap package you installed.  You extend the boostrap base template and override the blocks in it to create a page with a standard layout.  You still need to write bootstrap related markup.  This is explained right in the docs you linked to.

`my_project/templates/my_page.html`:

```html
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block title %}This is an example page{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Hello, Bootstrap</h1>
{% endblock %}
```